# Cómo instalar un paquete de github

Tags: r

Necesito instalar un paquete de github 
este es mi código:

```
devtools::install_github("jgalgarra/kcorebip")
```

ya tengo el devtool instalado pero me da el siguiente error:
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds
Esto es lo que tengo configurado en mi Rprofile.site:

```
# Things you might want to change

# options(papersize="a4")
# options(editor="notepad")
# options(pager="internal")

# set the default help type
# options(help_type="text")
  options(help_type="html")

# set a site library
# .Library.site <- file.path(chartr("\\", "/", R.home()), "site-library")

# set a CRAN mirror
# local({r <- getOption("repos")
#       r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
#       r["CRAN"] <-  http://cran.us.r-project.org
#options(repos=r)})

local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["Nexus"] <- "http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/"
       options(repos=r)

})


# Give a fortune cookie, but only to interactive sessions
# (This would need the fortunes package to be installed.)
#  if (interactive()) 
#    fortunes::fortune()
```

puedo modificar alguna línea para poder instalar del github o es otro problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es una falla en la conecction con github, no encontre documentación sobre una razón especifica.

Una posible solución seria descargar el zip del paquete desde github. Descomprimirlo por ejemplo en el disco C o en otra ruta y correr el siguiente codigo

```
devtools::install("C:\Ruta a la carpeta descomprimida\kcorebip")
```